Create a stencil to split a string, then edit each part, and then join again
I'm trying to create a stencil from here... https://stencil.fuller.li/en/latest/builtins.html
I want to...

Split a string by a character.
Edit each string (except the last)
Join the strings by a new character.

I have this at the moment using a filter.
{{myString|split:"/"|join:"."}}

This works but I can't work out how to put a new filter in between the split and the join to lowercase|capitalize each part of the string?
